# Connection Timeout Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2005, asp-classic

I have created a linked server from one SQL Server 2005 to Another 2005.  When I run an update query through the SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), it runs in under a second.  If I run the query through a asp webpage it times out.  I ran SQL Profiler to see if I noticed anything as well as the Activity Monitor in SSMS and all I found was that a lock was being created (Wait type LOCK_M_U), but I can't find what is locking it.  Any help would be appreciated.

Wade

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with the ADO activeX component, since I used ASP.Net and it worked flawlessly.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the user account that you run under in SSMS and from the ASP page have different permissions on the linked server, which could lead to a difference in which query plans it uses when running your update. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214146/slow-query-when-connecting-to-linked-server/4391365#4391365) to a more generic question about linked server performance.